# Horizontal Bootstrap 4 columns

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use the grid system of bootstrap 4, I want 3 columns(each of 4) and I need them in a horizontal manner. But I'm getting it in a vertical manner. Here's my code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-4 header-middle">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search Here..." / name="search" required="">
  <button type="submit" name=" submit">
    <img src ="Images/search.png" width ="48" height ="48"/>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 logo_agile">
  <h1>
    <a href="index.html">
      <span>E</span>lite Shoppy
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag top_logo_agile_bag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </h1>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough draft of what I think you are looking for. It still needs work on the scaling side. When you shrink the screen down it won't look pretty. Mess around with it to get it to your liking. Remove `class="container"` if you dont want the padding.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon2"><img src ="Images/search.png" width ="48" height ="48"/></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
      <h1>
        <a href="index.html">
          <span>E</span>lite Shoppy
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag top_logo_agile_bag" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
      Blank
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Nirav Soni, I think mainly you are just missing the `<div class="row"></div>` to wrap your `col-md-4`'s